# PHP Form scripting with rewrite cond

Tags: php, .htaccess

I am new to php scripting and im trying to create a contact form

this is the form i have (important part only)

```
<form data-name="Get In Touch Form" name="wf-form-Get-In-Touch-Form" action="contactform.php" </form>
```

i have rewrite conditions as follows

```
#remove html?
#RewriteEngine on
#RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} /([^.]+)\.html [NC]
#RewriteRule ^ /%1 [NC,L,R]

#RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.html -f
#RewriteRule ^ %{REQUEST_URI}.html [NC,L]

#remove php?
#RewriteEngine on
#RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} /([^.]+)\.php [NC]
#RewriteRule ^ /%1 [NC,L,R]

#RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.php -f
#RewriteRule ^ %{REQUEST_URI}.php [NC,L]
```

currently the rewrite condition is off and the form works but if i enable the conditions it will not work
how can i fix this issue?
Thanks

Comment: What do you mean by "it will not work"? How is that related to your form?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} /([^.]+)\.php [NC]
RewriteRule ^ /%1 [NC,L,R]
```

Here you are externally rewriting all requests that end with `.php` to the suffix-less version, and the browser will follow that redirect by making a GET request, which means you lose your POST data at this point.

Your form should directly point to `action="contactform"` instead of `action="contactform.php"`, then this does not happen in the first place.

(You can also add an exception to this by using a second RewriteCond, that checks if the request method was not POST first, so that this redirect does not happen in such cases.)